# 億? How to translate in numbers?

Tags: word-usage

Full text: この結果、連結売上高168億46百万円、連結営業利益24億5百万円、連結経常利益23億41百万円、連結当期純利益12億45百万円となりました.

My issue: How do we translate the numbers in English numerals? Will it be 1,245 million yen or 12.45 billion yen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 12億45百万円 = 12 x 100,000,000 + 45 x 1,000,000 = 1,245,000,000 = 1245 million yen = 1.245 billion yen

For the Europeans amongst you ',' is a separator and '.' is a decimal point in the above.

Comment: I was confused with billion and million, now the concept is clear to me. Thank you for your help